# how to get value from textbox on click of button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FoE5.jpg)

this is the image, in this, i have a button when I click the button it should show me the updated value of textbox into the alert box. I have coded something like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#Button1', function () {
var newStr = document.getElementsByName('input');
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++)
{
    str = str + newStr.item(i).value;
}
alert(str);    
});
```

But things are not working properly. Need help thanxx.

```
$(document).on('click', '#table1 tr', function () {
var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
$(tableData).each(function (index, value) {
    $('#txt' + index).val(value);
});
});
```

this is sending table data to the textbox. I just want to get all the value of textbox into one variable and want to check that value for further process.

Comment: your textbox doesn't have id?

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: Are you sure yout want to use getElementsByName()? Do the inputs have the name attribute with your value? Or do you mean getElementsByTagName('input')?

Comment: Post the complete Html and JS code. Sometimes a part of JS might conflict with other so it's always the best practice to share the entire code of page.

Comment: @hallleron it's not necessary to use that method only. You can also tell if there is a better way.

Comment: @teovankot they do have IDs

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar co code in HTML... all jquery

Comment: @sandeepgupta I think you should try debugging the variables by logging it in console. Just put console.log(newStr.item[i].value) in the for loop. Try this and tell us what do you see.

Comment: `str = str + newStr.item(i).value;` should be `str = str + newStr[i].value;`. As you are using jQuery you could use the `.each()` function insted of the `for` loop. And if you are concatenating a load of input strings you should use `+=`, or even better an array str[i] = newStr[i].value;

Comment: @WizardCoder Exactly, I did notice the same and hence asked OP to post the response from the console.

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and better explanation of expected results

Comment: newStr is blank... it is not getting any data

Comment: @sandeepgupta did you change the () to [] , I mean parentheses to brackets? Also you need to check if you've used the right selection with getElementsByName or not? "input" is a tag name so you should be using getElementsByTagName for it.

Comment: @AkshayR. yes...

Comment: Are you just trying grab all the input values and add a new row to your table? If so, then as mentioned earlier, please provide the complete HTML so we can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: @AkshayR. thanks it is done

Answer (score 0):

you haven't gave your `html`. but using this you can access all your input type.

```
$("#formID :input").each(function(){
     var input = $(this);
    });
```

or IF u want to access only `input type = text` 
use

```
$("#formID input[type=text]")
```

Hope this will help you out